# Java out of heap space with tons of free heap space

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "543" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2894)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:117)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:407)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:241)
```

In an application started with this command:

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx3072M -jar MyJar.jar >> /var/log/MyLog.log 2>&1 &
```

While the OS reported 27% of the 4GB RAM being used.

By my calculations there should have been almost 2GB of free heap space. Could it be that for some reason the JVM didn't increase the heap size from the starting one?

Is there anything that can cause this error with heap space actually available?

Note that this is all on a 1.6JVM. Specifically: java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.50.1.11.5.el6_3.x86_64

EDIT: The string that is being built cannot be 2GB long. It is constructed from a fixed length array of objects and cannot end up longer than a few hundred chars.

Comment: I would definitely change my design.

Comment: How did you obtain the 27% figure? Also, is there an explanation for why the OS's figure (27%) and your figure (~2GB) differ by a factor of two?

Comment: Activate `verbose GC` and show that result... furthermore, what the are you building with that StringBuffer?

Comment: Have you tired [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to analyse the memory consumption?

Comment: What the OS is telling you is available may not be accurate. Is it for the JVM process or the OS overall? It also may be a very big string you are copying so the JVM is telling you that it can't accommodate it. How big is this string? Also, I'm not sure in the JVM but it may need a contiguous chunk for this operation and it may not be available.

Comment: The OS is CentOS and there was nothing else running at that time. 27% is what it reported as reserved. My figure is 2GB free since the JVM was started with max heap size of 3GB and 27% of 4GB suggests that 1GB was taken. The StringBuffer was used by a JSON library and there is no way the string could be longer than a few hundred chars. I'll try the verbose GC.

Answer (score 1):

When java tries to allocate the memory (in your case on `Array#copyOf`) and sees it's impossible to fit maximal heap size specified with -Xmx option it does not perform actual allocation but throws OOM exception. This is why OS reports 27% of RAM being used.

Answer (score 0):

An OutOfMemoryError is thrown if the object being allocated does not fit on the heap. The heap may be segmented into generations depending on the garbage collector in use. If the array being allocated is larger than the appropriate memory segement even after garbage collection, the JVM might throw an OutOfMemory even though it still has memory left.

To verify whether this is the case, try logging the size of the array that could not be created.